# dir: cannot access in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Everytime I run my devops pipeline, I keep getting `dir: cannot access "..."` error messages. I have no idea why it happens.

[image: Error screenshot]

Here is my pipeline code:

```yaml
---
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: testrepo
    type: github
    endpoint: testendp
    name:  testrepo/data

trigger:
- none
pool:
  name: Hosted Ubuntu 1604
steps:
- checkout: testrepo
- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      data=$(jq 'to_entries | map(select(.value.isdata=="true")) | from_entries' datafiles.json )
      echo "$data"
```

But I am always getting the `dir: cannot access "..."` error.

Comment: In the code the script is supposed to be a bash script. In your output it is a powershell. How come?

Comment: Hi @rayaurelius, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Open project settings->Settings->check the option Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines and Limit job authorization scope to referenced Azure DevOps repositories.

You can refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#troubleshooting-authorization-for-a-yaml-pipeline) for more details.

[image]